# Having trouble replacing two arguments with an array & a number in a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, arguments

I'm new to coding and working on an assignment that asks the following:

> Using Javascript, please write a function foo, that takes two arguments, an array and a number, and returns true if the length of the array is equal to the second argument? E.g. `foo([1, 2, 3], 3)` would return true.

This is what I have come up with so far:

```
    var array = ["meow", "woof", "moo", "quack"];
    var num = 4;

    foo();
    function foo(x, y) {
     console.log(array.length);
    }
```

My problem is I can't change `x` to `array` and `y` to `num`. When I do I get:

```
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
        at foo:6:13
        at eval:4:1
        at eval
        at new Promise
```

Like I said, I'm very new to this all so I'm unsure if I'm creating the right function or breaking any rules.

Comment: `foo();` ... you're not passing any arguments to foo ... therefore `x, y` are undefined - you possibly want `foo(array, num)` ... then `x` will be `array` and `y` will be `num` - and you can `console.log(x.length)`

Comment: when calling the `foo` function the first argument should be `array` and the second argument should be `num`. Just like this `foo(array,num)`, and the definition of your function should be `console.log(x.length)`

Comment: Thank you! It worked when I placed the arguments inside the foo(); I was using to call.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you are not passing the arguments to the function foo, look at this example based on your task:

```
function foo(x,y){
  return (x.length === y);
}

var array = ["meow", "woof", "moo", "quack"];
var num = 4;

console.log(foo(array,num))
// returns true
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function takes in arguments so you want to build your function like so

```
var array = ["meow", "woof", "moo", "quack"];
    var num = 4;

function foo(x, y) {
     if(x.length === y) {
      return true
     }
    }
```

and pass your arguments into the function when calling it

```
foo(array, var);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function foo(array, num) {
    return array.length === num;
}
```

There you go :)

To pass arguments to a function they have to be present in the funcion definition

```
function foo(array, num)
```

and to call the function with the parameters you want just call

```
foo([1,2,3], 3)
```

Comment: really, you think that will work being invoked like `foo()` in the code in the question?